# Android - Double click publisher adview error

Tags: adview

I am working on an app with DFP ads.

I am facing one issue while loading DFP ads on my app with my app package name with one adunitId but same adunitId works in different apps. AdUnitId works in other apps but not in my current app.

Kindly find screenshots of sample apps in an attachment.[image][image]

Please guide me on this issue.